# Can you block redirections?

Tags: html, redirect

The HTML redirection will work on numerous websites, but It won't work on website like Youtube, Soundcloud.

Ex:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=https://soundcloud.com">
```

This does not work. Did Soundcloud block the redirections?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Are you making a userscript?

Comment: works for me in Chrome. I don't believe there's any way a receiving website could detect that you arrived via such a redirect.

Comment: Define "does not work".

Comment: @Hobbit I want to do a HTML redirection from my page to soundcloud, but it does not work.

Comment: @Zoidberd Nothing happens.

Comment: Does the dev console give any errors?

Comment: Refused to display 'https://soundcloud.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Comment: I'm doing a Facebook tab application, so I guess it's an iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a site cannot prevent another site from redirecting to it.

Comment: what does this have to do with redirects?

Comment: Everything if the redirect is in an iFrame! Should of told it was in an iFrame though.

Answer (score 0):

Test in another browser and check your network settings - it is not possible for a website to know how you visited it - they can only tell where you were before your landed on their site (via HTTP referrer)

Comment: And HTTP Referrer can easily be spoofed.

Comment: @Maxwell You didn't specify that this code was running from within an iframe. If it isn't, then that documentation isn't what you're looking for - but yes, sites can tell a browser not to load the page if it's in an iframe, but only if the browser understands that header. (Most modern browsers do)